# Java GridBagLayout with different number of rows in column

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Is it possible to have a GridBagLayout like this picture ? (Multiple columns with 4 rows + one column with 5 rows in this case)

GridBagLayout for calculator:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YlLP.png]

Comment: I would nest JPanels using various layouts for this such as GridLayout for the buttons and operations, BorderLayout for the overall.....

Answer (score 1):

For the last column create a separate panel that uses a `GridLayout`.

Then you add this panel to your main panel using the `GridBagLayout`. You would then need to specify a constraint using `gridheight=4`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on the various constraints you can use to customize the layout.

The trick to layout manager is the you are not forced to use a single panel and layout manager. You can nest panels with different layout managers to achieve your effect.